# Textbox list for jquery doesn't work with jquery

Tags: jquery, email, textboxlist

I know its a little absurd to ask this question. but Im having trouble using Textboxlist for jquery(`http://www.devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/`), when I tried to insert this jquery src:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

this is the result:

[image]

when removed:

[image]

this is the src for `Textboxlist for jquery`:

```
    <script src="mootools-1.2.1-core-yc.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>    
    <script src="GrowingInput.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../Source/TextboxList.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>     
    <script src="../Source/TextboxList.Autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../Source/TextboxList.Autocomplete.Binary.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly a problem with using jQuery and Mootools on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `jQuery.noConflict()` at http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries